# how do i identify which switch was pressed in listView

Tags: java, android

I have objects in a list view each with a switch. 
how do I identify which switch was pressed meaning which item it was included in. does list view have a method to tell me which object it was in the arraylist of the listview

Comment: will you please post code what you have tried?

Comment: I didn't try identify it because I have no idea how to do it. I am only able to detect which item in list is clicked no a switch in the item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily know which item is clicked in your `OnCheckedChangeListener()` by setting a tag with some definite information about the current `ListView` item using `button.setTag()` (you can put whatever Object you want in this tag). You will need this in your custom Adapter.

Which you call back in your Listener using `view.getTag()`. This call will return the same Object. You can then use this method to have a distinct id or string (most often the content of the current item in your arrayList) in each separate ListView.